# Why has Yahoo only managed to index TWO pages on my site?

Tags: search-engines, yahoo

I launched my site a few months ago, and Google already has over 1K indexed pages - whereas Yahoo has only managed to index 2 pages (when I check with Yahoo Site Explorer).

I have checked (using Yahoo Site Explorer), and no errors have been found by the Yahoo bot when indexing my site. Can anyone explain the discrepancy in number of archived pages?

Note: I dubmitted my sitemap to both search engines at about the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo's results are now powered mostly by Bing. Try submiting your site and sitemaps with [Bing Webmaster Tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmasters/).

Comment: Agreed, also YSE has been getting less and less accurate. Officially Yahoo has said it will remain intact and supported but that doesn't seem like it's the case.